# Working on JavaScript files takes a long time in visual studio 2017

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have this issue with visual studio 2017 that whenever i open a javascript file or try working and edit/add new lines, visual studio kinda goes to sleep (freeze) and keep telling me i am busy after like 5-10mins it comes back and same thing repeats and repeats, it is not only within javascript files but also within cshtml files as well. whenever i try to add new lines of javascript it happens, it kinda pisses me off since i have bunch of deadlines.

I tried to trace the issue, i saw this node.js process (Node.js: Server-side Javascript 32bit) that when i manually end its task, visual studio comes out of freeze.

> its location : G:\Program\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\Web\External\x86
>
> My Visual Studio Version is 15.7.1

Anyone else has this issue? how can i fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Visual Studio 2017 is using Node.JS Server Side Java script** which provide several functionalities like
Convert Typescript(TS) into JS and much more.

It takes lots of processing power which eventually hangs the Visual Studio mainly while comparing files with TFS.

**Solution**

**Just Go to Tools > Options > Text Editor > 
JavaScript/TypeScript > Language Service**

> Uncheck 'Enable the new JavaScript language service'.

This will prevent the NodeJS process from starting.**

Comment: i used your solution and i don't have any problem so far.  thank you.

Comment: Your welcom @Valkyrie . 
But this functionality is needed if you are using typescript of higher versions of Javascript like ES5, 6

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio is very heavy to edit Javascript. I think you can use other editor such as Web Storm or Sublime. It's very fast...

Comment: the point is that i didn't have the issue with vs 2015 or else, also when every files are within same application it really speed up the development

Answer (score 0):

These might help

1.Disable F1. (Environment->Keyboard) This is probably the best advice that I found somewhere.

2.Disable "Animate environment tools" (Environment->General).

3.Disable Start Page (Environment->Startup).

4.Disable "Track Active Item in Solution Explorer" (Projects and Solutions).

5.Disable Navigation Bar (Text Editor->C#). I think this is available for every language.

6.Set "AutoToolboxPopulate" to false (Windows Forms Designer).

7.You can set the Code view as the default view when viewing Windows Forms. Just right-click on the cs file and select "Open With...".

8.Open Visual Studio using the command line (devenv) rather than using the Start menu. I don't know why but I notice it loads faster.

9.Turn off Track Changes. (Text Editor->Track changes)